# How to assign a variable based on the output of a function

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I cannot figure out how to assign a variable based on the output of a function. I basically want to do this in my `__init__` method

```
def square(x):
    y = x * x
    return y

toSquare = 10
result = square(toSquare)
```

My init method looks like this

```
def __init__(self):
        self.init(
            hash = sp.bytes('0x'),
            nat_value = self.somefunction(),   <-this does not work

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contracts are codeless during origination. By this, I mean that you don't run any smart-contract code during origination.

Above, you are leveraging meta-programming to build the initial storage of the contract, and you cannot use any entry point function there.

**Example of what you can do:**

```
import smartpy as sp

class MyContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(b = self.a())

    def a(self):         
        b = 1
        return b

    @sp.entry_point        <- Only executable at runtime
    def ep(self):
        pass

@sp.add_test(name = "Sample")
def test():
   scenario = sp.test_scenario()
   c1 = MyContract()
   scenario += c1
   c1.ep()
```